# Proximity effect using Point distribute

Tags: geometry-nodes

How can I make this effect in blender using geometry nodes?
The two sphere is generated using Point Distribute and Point Instance.
I know it has something to do with Attribute Proximity but I don't know how to deal with it.
[image: Proximity Effect Example]

Comment: do you want explicitly a geometry nodes solution? because it is very easy with metaballs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, it is a solution without proximity...(shame on me), but i think it isn't possible with the current version of the proximity node (i explain it later)

ok, there is a "way" and it's a bit buggy, but you can instance a metaball in GN with a hack:

Add a metaball, parent it to a plane.

[image]

On the plane: check instance on vertices.

[image]

add GN modifier to plane with this node setup:

[image]

and you will see: nothing...

but...now click a few times in "as instance"

[image]

and you will see:

[image]

[image]

NOTE: I am pretty sure this isn't possible in GN with proximity node (except you just want to do it with 2 metaballs) because the proximity node looks like this:

[image]

And so it takes only one object/geometry where you get the proximity from. You don't get the proximity between all instances (or every near vertex) and so i think this isn't possible with the proximity node.

Comment: Thanks! That was what all I needed!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

This is not the answer to achieve exactly the result you've shown, it's just to show what other possibilities there are with *Geometry Nodes*.

For example, you can turn points into volumes and volumes back to meshes. In the following gif I just used two spheres, but of course you can use any other shape as well. This is done completely in *Geometry Nodes*, maybe one could go on by adding a *Remesh* modifier afterwards or something like that.

[image: volume meshing]

And this is my node setup:

[image: node tree]

Comment: Nice! Thank you for sharing your knowledge!